# error: no such column: blog_marketreview.name even when i have a field named name

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, frameworks

i get the error `no such column: blog_marketreview.name` even when i clearly have a field named name in my app blog and model marketreview. I HAVE done `makemigrations` and `migrate` but the error persists.
here is my models.py

```
class MarketReview(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(MarketPost, related_name="mreviews", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rate = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=RATE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.post.title, self.name)
```

here is the marketpost model that i connect to using foreignkey:

```
class MarketPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    post_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=False, upload_to='marketplace_images/')
    content = models.TextField()
    #content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('marketplace-detail', args=(str(self.id)))
```

and here the template that had an error during rendering:

```
    <hr>
27    <br><br>
28  
29    {% if not post.mreviews.all %}
30    <h4>No reviews yet... Be the first one!</h4>
31    <a href="{% url 'add-marketreview' post.pk %}">Add a Review</a>
32    
33  {% else %}
34  <a href="{% url 'add-marketreview' post.pk %}">Add a Review</a>
35  <br><br>
36    **{% for review in post.mreviews.all %} this line is in red**
37      <h4>{{ user.name }}</h4>
38      <b>{{ review.name }} - {{ review.date_added }}</b>
39      <br>
40      {{ review.body }}
41      <br>
42      <br>
43    {% endfor %}
44  {% endif %}
45  {% endblock content %}
```

and i ALSO get the error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: blog_category` even when i do have a model named category found in blog app. here it is:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    NameOfCategory = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.NameOfCategory

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
        return reverse('blog-home')
```

and i also ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` as well and the error persists. please help!

note: I also tried deleting migrations files and then the entire folder but that didn't do anything as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [this command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#migrate).

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Comment: i tried the error still is there

Comment: Maybe try to make another project.